How do you securely store environment variable on GCP App Engine Flex?
I have this setup:
Source Control - GitHub ( GH )
CI / CD - GH Actions ( Builds Docker Image and Push to Image Repo )
Image Repo - GCP Artifact Registry
Platform - GCP App Engine Flex
I have an app.yaml where the values are currently stored in plaintext.
I tried writing a Github Action Step were

GH Action will pull secrets from Actions Secrets and write it in an .env file
the .env file will be used to build the image.

It didn't work on GH Actions and docker image was not pulling the .env to build the image.

2 Comments: First, App Engine Flex is rarely the good choice today on Google Cloud. Secondly, if you have secret, put them in secret manager. Your GitHub action pipeline must pull the secret from Action Secret and push them to secret manager. Then, your app, at startup, should read secret from secret manager and keep them in memory. The secret must be in plain text only at runtime. Pro tips: If you deploy your image on Cloud Run instead, Cloud Run load automatically the secrets in env var in memory. You have nothing to change to your app like this.

@guillaumeblaquiere - very good suggestion. I moved to Cloud Run
